# Creating two new columns and removing the source column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following example data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A1","A2","A3","A4"),
                 NUM=c(469,586,394,595,398,203,604,809))
```

I am looking to extract the first value of the NUM column and place it in a new column NUM1, and then on the second occurrence of a NUM value for the same ID, extract that value into a new column NUM2. Finally, I would like to remove the original column. The dataset I have has many more variables and columns in addition to ID and NUM. The following is the desired output.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("A1","A2","A3","A4"),NUM1=c(469,586,394,595),NUM2=c(398,203,604,809))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. You will need to create a `COL` column as the name for the new columns, so in this case we use `group_by` and `str_c` to create this column. `pivot_wider` is an updated version of the `spread` function. All these functions are from the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(COL = str_c("NUM", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = COL, values_from = NUM) %>%
  ungroup()
df1
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   ID     NUM1  NUM2
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A1      469   398
# 2 A2      586   203
# 3 A3      394   604
# 4 A4      595   809
```

Answer (score 1):

using base R you could do:

```
 reshape(transform(df,time=cumsum(grepl("1",ID))),idvar = "ID",dir="wide",sep="")

  ID NUM1 NUM2
1 A1  469  398
2 A2  586  203
3 A3  394  604
4 A4  595  809
```

OR YOU COULD TRY:

```
`colnames<-`(t(unstack(df,NUM~ID)),c("NUM1","NUM2"))
   NUM1 NUM2
A1  469  398
A2  586  203
A3  394  604
A4  595  809
```

Answer (score 1):

@akrun 's eloquent Base R solution:

```
df1 <- aggregate(NUM ~ ID, df, I)
```

(My) Base R solution:

```
#Transform the dataframe: 

df1 <- within(df, {
              count_num_by_id <- ave(NUM, ID, FUN = seq.int);
              NUM2 <- ifelse(count_num_by_id == 2, NUM, 0);
              NUM <- ifelse(count_num_by_id == 1, NUM, 0);
              rm(count_num_by_id)})

# Aggregate the dataframe: 

df1 <- data.frame(aggregate(.~ID, df1, sum))
```

Comment: @akrun superb solution. I have amended mine above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first and second value of each `ID` by subsetting

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(NUM1 = NUM[1L], 
            NUM2 = NUM[2L])

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  ID     NUM1  NUM2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A1      469   398
#2 A2      586   203
#3 A3      394   604
#4 A4      595   809
```

If there are other columns that you want to maintain you can use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(NUM1 = NUM[1L], 
         NUM2 = NUM[2L]) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  select(-NUM)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution ...

```
require(data.table)

# Set as a data.table and create a unique row.
setDT(df)[, rid := paste0('NUM', rowid(ID))]

# Cast the data by ID and rid.
df <- dcast(df, ID ~ rid, value.var = 'NUM')

df
#    ID NUM1 NUM2
# 1: A1  469  398
# 2: A2  586  203
# 3: A3  394  604
# 4: A4  595  809
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232239/3817004) `dcast()` approach which calls `rowid()` directly in the formula and also will handle additional columns in `df`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID + ... ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "NUM"), value.var = "NUM")
```

> ```
>    ID NUM1 NUM2
> 1: A1  469  398
> 2: A2  586  203
> 3: A3  394  604
> 4: A4  595  809
> ```

Note the `prefix = "NUM"` parameter in the call to `rowid()`.

#### Additional columns in `df`

The OP has pointed out that his *dataset [...] has many more variables and columns in addition to ID and NUM*.

***If*** the values of the additional columns are identical for each `ID` then `+ ...` will add them to the output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"),
  NUM = c(469, 586, 394, 595, 398, 203, 604, 809),
  other1 = rep(4:1, 2),
  other2 = rep(letters[1:4], 2)
)

df2
```

> ```
>   ID NUM other1 other2
> 1 A1 469      4      a
> 2 A2 586      3      b
> 3 A3 394      2      c
> 4 A4 595      1      d
> 5 A1 398      4      a
> 6 A2 203      3      b
> 7 A3 604      2      c
> 8 A4 809      1      d
> ```

```
dcast(setDT(df2), ID + ... ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "NUM"), value.var = "NUM")
```

> ```
>    ID other1 other2 NUM1 NUM2
> 1: A1      4      a  469  398
> 2: A2      3      b  586  203
> 3: A3      2      c  394  604
> 4: A4      1      d  595  809
> ```